# Criterion for finite time blowup of an ODE

Tags: differential-equations

Hi I'm trying to understand the most general conditions under which I can conclude finite time blow up of an ODE of the form $\dot{x} = f(x)$ with initial condition $x_0 > 0$ and $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$.

If I re-write this in a separable way so that $dt = \frac{dx}{f(x)}$ then I want to determine if there is some finite time $T$ for which $x(T) = \infty$. Ok so it is clear to me that if $\int_{x_0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{f(x)} = \infty$ then there is **no finite time blowup** for the initial condition $x_0$ (since we would need some finite $T$ for which $x(T)=\infty$ and this precludes that). I'm confused however if this is a necessary condition. In other words, if I know that $\int_{x_0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{f(x)} < \infty$ does this necessarily tell me that I **DO** get finite time blowup? This is my question. It's not entirely clear to me why this should *prove* finite time blowup.

Two examples to keep in mind in all of this are $f(x) = x^2$ (finite time blowup) and $f(x) = x^{1/2}$ (no finite time blowup).

Comment: Please read over your question again. I think your first improper integral equation should be an inequality.  Also, you misspelled separable.

Comment: The spelling error is corrected but I do indeed want to say that integral diverges. It is saying that if x does to infinity then $T$ must also go to infinity.

Comment: Think about $f(x) = x^2$ versus $f(x) = x^{1/2}$ to get the divergence/convergence ideas right.


Comment: Ok I will make a modification. 

Comment: The condition you're talking about (with the additional constraints mentioned in Willie Wong's answer) is called *Osgood’s condition* and known since 1898. See Walter's *Ordinary Differential Equations* (1998 ed., Springer GTM 182), [p. 147](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZSK6LU_z0wIC&pg=PA147).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This used to be a comment, but I think it deserves to be an answer, after mulling over it a bit.)

I don't think your criteria are quite correct. Some counterexamples:

Let $f(x) = - x^2$, and $x(0) = -1$. This ODE blows up in finite time toward $-\infty$. But $\int_{-1}^\infty dx / f(x) $ diverges due to the singularity at $x = 0$.

Similarly, for any $f(x)\geq 0$ such that $f(0) = 0$, for any initial value $x(0) < 0$ we must have $x(0) \leq x(t) \leq 0$ for any $t > 0$. Hence we have global existence (no blow up). But if we take $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ if $|x| \leq 1$ and $f(x) = x^2$ if $|x| > 1$, then $1/f(x)$ is integrable, and in particular $\int_{x_0}^\infty dx/f(x) < \infty$ for any $x_0$.

One key point used in your examples $f(x) = x^2$ and $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ with initial data positive, is that there are no stationary points. And so for any positive initial datum the evolution eventually goes toward $x\to \infty$, and so the question of blowup reduces to a question of how fast that happens. And for that the integral test is a good one.

Another way of saying this is that you wanted to use the equality

$$ \int_0^s dt = \int_{x(0)}^{x(s)} \frac{dx}{f(x)} $$

but you falsely presupposed that the end state is necessarily $x(s) = \infty$.

Comment: Note that by horizontally translating $f$, the second example can be made so that your modified criteria that $x_0 > 0$ is satisfied. 

Comment: If you strengthen your assumption to $f(x) > 0$, allowing no stationary solutions, then the blow-up criterion boils down to the integral equality I wrote down at the bottom of my answer. 